# How to lock keys/keypad programmatically in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to lock specific keys/whole keypad programmatically in Windows Phone 7.

Is there any API available for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. Nothing of the sort is available today, and nor is it going to be when the Mango update is released this fall.

I think I'm speaking for all Windows Phone users when I say such functionality should never be exposed. Think "denial of service"!

Answer (score 1):

You can determine which virtual keyboard (SIP) the user sees by specifying the `InputScope` for the relevant `TextBox` controls. The complete list is documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and there are some screenshots in [Jeff Blankburg's blog post](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/10/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-10-inputscope-textboxes/).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through the native (read: unofficial, unsupported) API - each device has its own, and I know that on my Dell Venue Pro I can lock any physical key on the device. As of virtual (software) keys - you cannot lock them through the SDK and all you can do is handle events as keystrokes are sent from the keyboard to the receiver (e.g. a TextBox control).